# What is taking up my disk space?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have an old Windows 7 box that is used as a media centre. There are 2 partitions: C contains all the sys files, and all the data is stored on D.
For some reason, the C drive has been filling up with more and more data recently, and I can't figure out why.

Here can you can clearly see that the C drive is [using almost 200GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiY6B.png)

I then ran WinDirStat and it looks to me like there is only about [50GB being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTmcK.png).

I would expect that the usage should be much closer to 50GB, than 200GB, because that drive is only used for system files. Any ideas on how I can find out what is actually using all this space and how I can get it down?

Comment: You should probably right-click WinDirStat and select "Run as administrator" then post the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **WinDirStat** on the menu click in **Options** and in there on **Show Unknown** (or use the shortcut <kbd>F7</kbd>) and you'll see WinDirStat shows a new item like a folder called  which will probably be the size missing between 50GB and 188GB.

This **Unknown** is basically folders that WinDirStat was unable to access.

The 1st thing to do - if this isn't how you've done it the first time - is to run WinDirStat As Administrator and see if that way some more gigs show up in their locations.

But some of the files WinDirStat will be unable to access even when running as Admin. Here is from the [WinDirStat blog](https://blog.windirstat.net/20061013/unknown-space/):

> WDS cannot access the files under System Volume Information on all the
> (NTFS?) drives, so it cannot sum up the sizes of these items. And by
> the way, we have had reports of up to 30 GB of Unknown space.
>
> Now what is stored in this directory? If you could gain SYSTEM access
> (and I will not tell you how that is possible …), you would see that
> the system keeps some binary log files there, but these take up only a
> small portion of what is stored in there. The biggest portion is
> usually being taken up by the System Restore Points (SRPs) you can
> create (or that are automatically created by software installers). The
> contents are a dump of the registry at the time the SRP was taken and
> of relevant files (usually from the system folders).

In that case, that says after running the program as administrator and still seeing a large amount of storage in that unknown black-whole... the next course of action would be deleting the old Restore Points saved and limiting the space it is allowed to use in the future.

### Delete all old restore points

1. Open `Control Panel` > `System and Security` > `System` and click on `System protection` on the left side panel.
2. Under the `Protection Settings` section, click to select the System Disk (`C:`) and then click `Configure`.
3. Here click on the `Delete` at `Delete all restore points (this includes system settings and previous versions of files).`

### Change Maximum Disk Space Used by System Protection

1. At the aforementioned window move the `Max Usage` slider to the left to the number you want it to be allowed to use. (do something like 10%)
2. Click `Apply` to apply the setting
3. (optional) Click `Create` and follow the steps to create a new Restore Point (after you've deleted all the old ones, it can't bother to create one.)